# Xamarin.Android Geolocation service is too slow

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, geolocation, gps

We'd like to get the latitude & longitude from a smartphone, and then use this information to get the address of the user.

This is taking almost a minute to get the latitude & longitude by using the example provided here: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location/

Also, we weren't able to get the address associated with the latitude & longitude. "address.MaxAddressLineIndex" is always zero.

- Is there a faster way to get the latitude & longitude?
- How can we get the address from this information efficiently?

Thanks.

Comment: You should be using the "Fused Location Provider" that is provided by Google Play Services (unless you are running on custom Android devices that do not have the Play Services installed. If so you can look at 3rd-party location services

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @SushiHangover This was the best answer so far. You may consider writing this as an answer.